# Gmail inbox message retrieval from deletion

Tags: gmail

I deleted a message inadvertently from my Gmail account on December 22, 2014. Is there anyway I can retrieve this message?

Answer (score 1):

I fear not, for all practical purposes. Messages in [Trash](https://support.google.com/a/answer/151128?hl=en) are permanently deleted after 30 days.